# Mysql takes long time on "sending data" thread, and select are to slow to execute

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

When loading of server rise above 500 query per sec, there are appearance threads with State "Sending data". And those threads i see very long time (more then 300 sec). Then all my applications witch using DB go down. This threads usually contained very simple select query.

However I have no idea what is going wrong, and tried to find some long query, but if I execute those query when server is ok (no Sending data thread), mysql run those query quickly. The impression is that when mysql open threads with state "sending data", mysql keep waiting until some queries are executed, and than others queires pending on mysql are relieved.

```
-------- Storage Engine Statistics
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA 
[--] Data in FEDERATED tables: 1G (Tables: 236)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 341G (Tables: 689)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 98G (Tables: 347)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 189


-------- Performance Metrics
[--] Up for: 20d 18h 54m 11s (2 q [0.000 qps], 7M conn, TX: 189B, RX: 263B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 100% / 0%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Physical Memory     : 125.9G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 1427.3G
[--] Other process memory: 410.6M
[--] Total buffers: 102.3G global + 452.0M per thread (3000 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 780M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 1885.1G (1497.33% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 1427.3G (1133.74% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/2)
[!!] Highest connection usage: 100%  (4037/3000)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (59/7827545)
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[OK] No Sort requiring temporary tables
[OK] No joins without indexes
[OK] No tmp tables created on disk
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (79K created / 7M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 100% (83K open / 0 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 14% (9K/65K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (515M immediate / 515M locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 99.97% ( 44160429 Memory / 44173731 Total)


-------- ThreadPool Metrics
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.


-------- Performance schema
[--] Performance schema is enabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 780.2M
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.


-------- MyISAM Metrics
[!!] Key buffer used: 31.3% (84M used / 268M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 256.0M/3.5G
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (259M cached / 49K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 46.9% (91M cached / 48M writes)


-------- InnoDB Metrics
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 102.0G/341.1G
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 64
[OK] InnoDB Used buffer: 99.02% (6619089 used/ 6684608 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.99% (738936273412 hits/ 739012463885 total)
[OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 99.86% (1798895351 hits/ 1801355285 total)
[!!] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (4 waits / 2459934 writes)


-------- Recommendations 
General recommendations:
Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
Dedicated this server to your database for highest performance.
Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage

Variables to adjust:
*** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
*** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
max_connections (> 3000)
wait_timeout (< 30)
interactive_timeout (< 30)
innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 341G) if possible.
```

**UPDATED**

Follow my innodb status:

```sql
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb%';
```

```
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  Loaded 5229057/6046204 pages
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   6205937
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   100531068928
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  215554
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  3118301184
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    149804400
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   65268
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   413403
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  6684608
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   158461330
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   19250
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    790263475017
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    81109709
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   25028408011
Innodb_data_fsyncs  28611060
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   1
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    3536522137600
Innodb_data_reads   253254058
Innodb_data_writes  108997574
Innodb_data_written 3780784608768
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  94227500
Innodb_dblwr_writes 10088862
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
Innodb_log_waits    4
Innodb_log_write_requests   1870088652
Innodb_log_writes   2611871
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    2822702
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   844031787520
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    20238775
Innodb_pages_read   252283573
Innodb_pages_written    94227500
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    30724065
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    3752
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    301607
Innodb_row_lock_waits   8188
Innodb_rows_deleted 457425761
Innodb_rows_inserted    731899599
Innodb_rows_read    1126973373393
Innodb_rows_updated 515680603
Innodb_num_open_files   714
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
```

Comment: Tuning seems fine, though you might have troubles with so much data in MyISAM tables if they are being used - concurrent updates block. Take a look at [fixing your slow query settings](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis) and include those queries and tables structures in a question along with `EXPLAIN {query}`.

Comment: Your server is going down due to too many connections. Setting max_connections  to a reasonable number (100?) that is supported by the hardware will prevent it going down when the queries back up (and prevent the too much memory usage warnings in this output could be occurring when connections reach max_connections).

Comment: Thanks folks, I will take a look at those recommendations. What I think strange is that even when I kill a query, it gives me the state "killed" on processlist for more than 5 seconds and than disappear from the list, but when the server is "normal" the kill command is stantly. I also notice that when the problem happens, I can connect to mysql, if I run the same query when processlist is "empty", the same query run about 1s. Is there any variable or something on innodb status that could help me to identify it? Could it be something related to IO? Thanks for help me.

Comment: Hard to say, more details needed. You seem to have one query in mind so maybe start with that, edit question to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for all tables in the query, the query itself and `EXPLAIN {query}`. If they are all innodb tables, sure might be something, include `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb%'`.

Comment: I updated my post with detail from innodb status. Is there anything strange there?

Comment: I also tried to reduce max_connections, I set it to 1000, however when I run the mysqltuner.pl script, it shows me to increase this variable.
max_connections (> 1000)

Comment: Interesting that your innodb status show inserts/update/deleted rows however mysql tuner shows 100% reads - its obviously wrong.  Focus on your slow queries. Its getting a bit repetitive saying that. You are reaching max_connections because your queries are slow. You can't tune your way out of this.